# RichEditBox PointerPressed Event Won't be fired in UWP?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

what i have tried is?

XAML Code:

```
  <Grid x:Name="grid" Width="500">
    <RichEditBox Height="32" PointerPressed="RichEditBox_PointerPressed" Background="Transparent" ></RichEditBox>
</Grid>
```

C# code:

```
    private void RichEditBox_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       Debug.WriteLine("Hello");
    }
```

When I click on RichEditBox,the PointerPressed Evnt won't be fired.I don't know what's the issue was?

In addition to that,when I right click on RichEditBox,it shows the default contextMenu(bold,italic,paste,..),I don't want it .How to stop this also?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When I click on RichEditBox,the PointerPressed Evnt won't be fired.

PointerRoutedEventArgs has [Handled bool property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/events-and-routed-events-overview#input-event-handlers-in-controls). If any `PointerEventHandler` marks this `Handled` as `true`, the event handler chain doesn’t proceed anymore.
The designer of the `RichEditBox` control had to hook the `PointerPressed` event for some obvious reason, and in the handler, the `Handled` was set to `true`. As a result, the handler you added to the event won’t be invoked.

You can use the [AddHandler event handing technique](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/events-and-routed-events-overview#registering-handlers-for-already-handled-routed-events) to specify that you want the `PointerPressed` event handler to be invoked even if the event is marked handled with the third argument set as true, like this:

```
richEditBox.AddHandler(RichEditBox.PointerReleasedEvent, new PointerEventHandler(RichEditBox_PointerPressed), true);
```

However, you maybe also note that the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.addhandler?view=winrt-19041) says “Do not routinely ask to rehandle a routed event, because it interferes with the intended design of the Windows Runtime event system for control compositing.”

In addition to the above method, we can also use `PointerCaptureLost` event which can be invoked when you click the `RichEditBox` control to replace `PointerPressed` event.

> In addition to that,when I right click on RichEditBox,it shows the default contextMenu(bold,italic,paste,..),I don't want it .How to stop this also?

You can add a new `Flyout` with the `Visibility` property set to `Collapsed` to replace the original `Flyout`, as a result, no ContextMenu will show when you right click on `RichEditBox` control. For example:

```
<RichEditBox x:Name="box" Width="100" Height="32" >
    <RichEditBox.ContextFlyout>
        <Flyout>
            <Flyout.FlyoutPresenterStyle>
                <Style TargetType="FlyoutPresenter">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                </Style>
            </Flyout.FlyoutPresenterStyle>
         </Flyout>
    </RichEditBox.ContextFlyout>
</RichEditBox>
```

Comment: Has your problem been solved? If it is not solved, please feel free to contact us.

Comment: yeah.Its Solved.Thanks